# Angular test component mock does not override regular component

Tags: angular, unit-testing, mocking

I am writing an unit test for my component AskComponent. I want to mock the embedded component EditComponent as described in https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#component-with-a-dependency
test-scipt:

```
import {ComponentFixture, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';

import {AskComponent} from './ask.component';
import {HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController} from "@angular/common/http/testing";
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Component} from "@angular/core";

@Component({standalone: true, selector: 'stt-edit', template: ''})
class EditStubComponent {
  constructor() {
    console.log('edit stub new');
  }
}

describe('AskComponent', () => {
  let httpClient: HttpClient;
  let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;
  let askComponent: AskComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AskComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [EditStubComponent, AskComponent, HttpClientTestingModule]
    })
      .compileComponents();
    httpClient = TestBed.inject(HttpClient);
    httpTestingController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AskComponent);
    askComponent = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(askComponent).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

EditComponent:

```
\\import ...
@Component({
  selector: 'stt-edit',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ ...  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => EditComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  templateUrl: './edit.component.html',
  styleUrl: './edit.component.css'
})
export class EditComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  constructor() {
    console.log('edit new');
  }
  // ...
}
```

when I run the test, the mock component is not used, as I can see by the 'edit new' console output. Only if I change the 'stt-edit' selector in EditComponent to something like 'stt-edit2', EditStubComponent is injected.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it, using [`overrideModule`](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/TestBed#overridemodule) then we can remove `ChildComponent` and add `ChildStubModule` this will solve the issue!

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ChildComponent } from './child/child.component';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

@Component({ standalone: true, selector: 'app-child', template: '' })
class ChildStubComponent {
  constructor() {
    console.log('edit stub new');
  }
}

describe('AskComponent', () => {
  let askComponent: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.overrideModule(AppModule, {
      remove: {
        imports: [ChildComponent],
      },
      add: {
        imports: [ChildStubComponent],
      },
    }).compileComponents();
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    askComponent = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(askComponent).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-hkyisv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.spec.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fmain-testing.ts,node_modules%2F%40angular%2Fcore%2Ftesting%2Findex.d.ts)

Comment: It's a standalone component, so overrideModule doesn't work. overrideComponent did the job.

Comment: @Galdor ok great!

Answer (score 0):

A solution is:

```
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ AskComponent, HttpClientTestingModule]
    })
      .overrideComponent(EditComponent,{
        set:{
          selector:'stt-edit',template:''
        }
      })
      .compileComponents();
```

I wonder if the angular documentation is wrong!